# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), found shape=(None, 3, 28, 28, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

```
image_w = 28
image_h = 28
  
X = []
Y = []
  
for idex, categorie in enumerate(categories):
    label = [0 for i in range(num_classes)]
    label[idex] = 1
    image_dir = img_path + categorie + '/'
  
    for top, dir, f in os.walk(image_dir):
        for filename in f:
            img = cv2.imread(image_dir+filename)
            img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=image_w/img.shape[1], fy=image_h/img.shape[0])
            img=img/256
            X.append(img.reshape(-1,28,28,1))
            Y.append(label)
 
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
 
train_input, test_input, train_target, test_target = train_test_split(X,Y)
```

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

```
train_scaled = np.append(train_input, test_input, axis=0)
train_target = np.append(train_target, test_target, axis=0)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')
checkpoint_cb=keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('best-cnn-model.h5', save_best_only=True)
early_stopping_cb=keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2, restore_best_weights=True)
history=model.fit(train_scaled, train_target, epochs=20, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=4, callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb])
```

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), found shape=(None, 3, 28, 28, 1)
Creating a CNN model that classifies images. An error occurred in the process of slightly modifying the model that was made to work well using fashion Mnist data.

I tried to modify the number of Dense layers or the size of Conv2D layers, but I couldn't fix it because the size of the input layer and the output layer were different.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in preparing the images and stacking them, specifically in this line:

```
X.append(img.reshape(-1,28,28,1))
```

Because I think your images are RGB, meaning they have 3-channels, meaning their shape is (28, 28, 3), so when you are applying the previous reshape, the resulted image will have the shape (3, 28, 28, 1). And your input_layer is expecting the data to be (28, 28, 1).

To solve it you have to disable this reshape and either use single channel data with keeping your input_layer as it is, or use the 3-channels and then assign your input_layer the shape=(28, 28, 3).